# Drupal Openlayers, doesn't show in IE

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, openlayers

My site is almost done, but ofc the major thing of the site is not working in IE, that is the map.

The map it self seems not to show, or it does, but not much of it, i've embedded a screen.

[image: Map issue]

it can be seen here, idaglobal.reload.dk

Also here is an export http://pastebin.com/KhzmHKwS

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug, i would seem that IE had issues using the blank.gif in the default dark theme.

Removing is fixes the problem, however maybe a blank.png will do instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also removing `blank.gif` from `openlayers/themes/default_dark/img/` was helpful when IE said

> Error during map rendering: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #.